# Spring beans declaration - is it more than just context awareness?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

As a newcomer to Spring, it is my understanding that beans declared in an XML file tell the ApplicationContext about the entities in the project that are to be beans we wish for Spring to manage. Consequently, when a context is started up, we can ask it to provide us those beans. So in this sense, the XML beans declaration file acts as a 'guide or manifest' to the `ApplicationContext` on what objects we wish for it to manage and hence become aware of them.

But then recently, while working with the Quartz scheduler via Spring, I observed that just declaring a bean of the Quartz scheduler class causes the context to start up a Quartz scheduler instance as is apparent from the application's log messages upon start up. So apparently with some types of classes when declared as beans, the ApplicationContext does more than just become aware that they exist and might need to be instantiated etc. (with regards to their DI needs ofcourse)? What tells the context that in the case of some kinds of beans to actually go ahead and instantiate them upon application start up even before explicitly calling a method of the sort `context.getBean('blah blah')` from application/user code? What controls this behavior?

Comment: Singletons beans are initialized eagerly (by default).

Comment: http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#beans-factory-lazy-init